# How to make dynamic state for multiple Collapse (functional component)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I want a collapse for each data in the state and just click on each one to open it.
These are my codes:

```
import ListSubheader from '@mui/material/ListSubheader';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse';
import ExpandLess from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMore from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';

const MyClass = ({data}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)

 const handleClick = () =>{
   setOpen(!open)

 };

  return (
    <List
    sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}
    component="nav"
    aria-labelledby='{item.listCities.id}'
    subheader={
      <ListSubheader component="div" id='{item.listCities.id}'>
              Lists
            </ListSubheader>
          }>
            {
          data.map(item =>
              <Box component="section" key={item.listCities.id}>
                <ListItemButton onClick={handleClick}>
                  <ListItemText primary={item.listCities.city} />
                  {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                </ListItemButton>
                <Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                    <List component="div" disablePadding>
                      <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
                        <ListItemText primary={item.listCities.names} />
                      </ListItemButton>
                    </List>
                </Collapse>
              </Box>
           )
        }
    </List>
  )   
}
```

And this is my component where it is called with this data:

```
  const ListItems= [
    {
      listCities:{city: "one", id:"1", names: ["name 1", "name 2", "name 3"]}
    },
    {
      listCities:{city: "two", id:"2", names: ["name 1", "name 2", "name 3"]}
    }
  ]



<MyClass data={ListItems}></MyClass>
```

I have used this API: 
https://mui.com/components/lists/#nested-list

Thanks if anyone knows help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way does the code shown not work as expected?  What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use an array in the state to store your objects in addition of a new element named `isOpen`, to test for each object is it open or not. To do that you can use the hook `useEffect()`, to run a function each time the arrived data changed to process it and add the new element for each object like this:

```
import ListSubheader from '@mui/material/ListSubheader';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import ListItemButton from '@mui/material/ListItemButton';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import Collapse from '@mui/material/Collapse';
import ExpandLess from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandLess';
import ExpandMore from '@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore';

const MyClass = ({data}) => {
  const [objectsList, setObjectsList] = React.useState([])

 const handleClick = (item) =>{
   setObjectsList(
      objectsList.map(e => e.listCities.id === item.listCities.id ? ({...e, isOpen: !e.isOpen} ) : (e))
   )
 };

 React.useEffect(() => {
    setObjectsList(
       data.map(e => ({...e, isOpen: false}))
    );
 }, [data])

  return (
    <List
    sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}
    component="nav"
    aria-labelledby='{item.listCities.id}'
    subheader={
      <ListSubheader component="div" id='{item.listCities.id}'>
              Lists
            </ListSubheader>
          }>
            {
          objectsList.map(item =>
              <Box component="section" key={item.listCities.id}>
                <ListItemButton onClick={() => handleClick(item)}>
                  <ListItemText primary={item.listCities.city} />
                  {item.isOpen ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                </ListItemButton>
                <Collapse in={item.isOpen} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                    <List component="div" disablePadding>
                      <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
                        <ListItemText primary={item.listCities.names} />
                      </ListItemButton>
                    </List>
                </Collapse>
              </Box>
           )
        }
    </List>
  )   
}
```

Comment: This code is incorrect! I want to fill this list from Props Data.

Comment: when i used the React.useEffect im getting the data from the props and putting it to the state `objectsList` and adding to it the variable of test `isOpen` , so thats why im using `objectsList` in the rest of the code, and please what is the incorrect on it?

Comment: Yes, your code does not work for me and the menus open and close at the same time. Does it work properly for you?

Comment: @hope I updated my answer and it's working properly now, just remember if you changed the structure of your object then you should change the comparison test to update the `isOpen` state for the right element, `e.listCities.id === item.listCities.id`

Comment: Thank you, your answer is correct 

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Haroun Darjaj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13794842/haroun-darjaj) answer, we can manage it simplier by user index of array:

```js
const [isOpenCollapse, setIsOpenCollapse] = useState(null);

const handleOpen = (clickedIndex) => {
  if (isOpenCollapse === clickedIndex) {
    setIsOpenCollapse(null);
  } else {
    setIsOpenCollapse(clickedIndex);
  }
};

[...]

return (
  <List>
    {arr.map((elm, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <ListItem key={elm.ID} onClick={() => handleOpen(index)} id="listItem">
            {isOpenCollapse === index ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
            <Box>
              <Typography>{elm.label}</Typography>
            </Box>
          </ListItem>
          <Collapse in={isOpenCollapse === index} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
            <p>PUT SOMETHING HERE</p>
          </Collapse>
        </>
      );
    })}
  </List>;
)
```